# How to get data from DynamoDB sorted by timestamp ? - NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda, dynamodb-queries

I want to get data form dynamoDB, shorted by timestamp. Anyone can help? My code is given below.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const dynamoDbClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const USERS_TABLE = process.env.USERS_TABLE;

const getNews = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //dynamodb params
    const params = {
      TableName: USERS_TABLE,
      FilterExpression: "PK = :this",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":this": "newsTable" },
    };
    //get dynamodb data
    const data = await dynamoDbClient.scan(params).promise();
    res.status(200).send({ data: data });
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).send({ message: e.message });
  }
};

module.exports = { getNews };
```

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1: Keep Scan; Sort client-side

> Works for small tables only. Single `Scan` call will scan only the first 1 MB of data in the table.

If you're doing `scan` operation as in your code example, it's impossible to get results sorted from DynamoDB. The only way to sort them is on client-side after you download all your data from database.

Replace:

```js
res.status(200).send({ data: data });
```

With:

```js
res.status(200).send({data: data.sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date)});
```

However, this is not recommended, since Scan operation without pagination will scan only 1st MB of data in your table. So you could get partial results. Possible solutions are:

## Option 2: (recommended) Don't use Scan; Use Query; Sort by secondary key

> This will work if you have your timestamp in the secondary key of the table

Don't use Scan; Use [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html) -- that way you can sort your data by `SK` (secondary key) by passing the `ScanIndexForward: false` to get the most recent results first.

Assuming you have such a table schema, where a timestamp is in the secondary key:

| PK | SK | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| newsTable | 2022-01-01 | some-1@example.com |
| newsTable | 2022-02-01 | some-2@example.com |
| newsTable | 2022-03-01 | some-3@example.com |

You can change your code from:

```js
    const params = {
      TableName: USERS_TABLE,
      FilterExpression: 'PK = :this',
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {':this': 'newsTable'},
    };
    //get dynamodb data
    const data = await dynamoDbClient.scan(params).promise();
```

To:

```js
    const params = {
      TableName: USERS_TABLE,
      KeyConditionExpression: 'PK = :this',
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {':this': 'newsTable'},
      ScanIndexForward: false,
    };
    //get dynamodb data
    const data = await dynamoDbClient.query(params).promise();
```

And it will return results sorted from database already.

If you don't have a timestamp in your secondary key, and you cannot add it, you can add [Local Secondary Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html) or [Global Secondary Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html).

## Option 3: Keep Scan, but paginate; Sort client-side

> Works if you cannot change DB schema and cannot switch your code to the Query operation.

Beware, it will be much more expensive, much slower. The larger the table, the slower it gets.

If you absolutely need to use Scan, you need to paginate through all the pages of the Scan operation, and then sort results in the JS code, like I described before. I've developed [a handy library](https://github.com/shelfio/dynamodb-parallel-scan) that makes scanning in parallel and supports pagination.